# How to add CometChat in my Django project?

Tags: django, django-models

Is there a way to add this chat in my django project? :

http://www.cometchat.com/

Comment: You don't need the separate PHP server. All you need is it's JS and CSS in your page. Now they even have a cloud solution you can look for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to run it in a separate page on a php enabled server. I guess you could include the chat interface in your django page using an iframe.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a separate PHP page... Neither then and not even now.

It has a new Cloud Version.
Refer:
https://developer.cometchat.com/docs/web-quick-start